# HTML5 clipboardData/FileReader seeing all file types as "image/png"

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob, clipboard, filereader

I am using a combination of clipboardData and FileReader to allow users to paste files and upload them to a chat webapp. Due to the nature of this process, I need to have separate handling for text, images, and other files.

Currently, plain text and images work fine, and they call the appropriate condition, but when I paste any other kind of file (.docx, .php, etc.) I still see "image/png" in my console as the clipboard item type, which understandably leads to the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.(…)

Is there any way to figure out why this is happening? I would expect that non-image files would be seen differently by the clipboard API.

Here is my current code:

```
  $(document).on('paste', "#textBox", function (ev) {
  console.log("pasted");
  var clipboardData = ev.originalEvent.clipboardData;

  $.each(clipboardData.items, function (i, item) {
      console.log(item.type);
      if (item.type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $( "#modalTrigger" ).trigger( "click" );
              $("#imgPreview").attr('src', e.target.result);
          }
          console.log("pasted image");
          reader.readAsDataURL(item.getAsFile());
      }
      else if (item.type.indexOf("text/plain") !== -1) {
        console.log("pasted regular text");
      }
      else {
        //NEVER REACHES THIS
        console.log("pasted other");
      }
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using the filereader and waste cpu - use `URL.createObjectURL(file)`

Comment: @Endless Is there any benefit other than memory purposes?